# How to get duplicate substring in DB2 sql

Tags: sql, db2

How to get duplicate sub string in DB2 sql
my scenario is that, I have one column

```
col1

| ABC_1      |

| ABC_3      |

|  WXY_5     |
```

I want to get only Duplicate sub string data with there addition of remaining sub values

```
    String       addn of substring values

|   ABC        | |     4       |

|   WXY        | |     5       |
```

4 is the addition of duplicate sub string value for that I have used query is that `SUM(CAST(SUBSTR(a.ref1, LOCATE('-',a.ref1)+1) as DECIMAL))` as output

but how to do it ?

Please give me a any suggestion ?

Comment: Given the statement you posted, we're going to need to see sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your last post, i suppose you can do simply it:

```
SELECT T2.VAL, sum(T3.VAL) total 
FROM RIDW.VW_REQUEST T1
INNER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T2 ON T2.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T2.NAME='owner_1' AND T1.REQUEST_ID <> -1 
INNER JOIN JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_DECIMAL_EXT T3 ON T3.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T3.NAME='resource1'
WHERE (T1.PROJECT_ID, T1.REQUEST_TYPE, T1.ISSOFTDELETED)  = (0,  'Task', 0) 
group by T2.VAL
```

Comment: Can we add two or more group by for two or more column in same query

Comment: We can do everything in SQL for data selection, but then it depends on what you want to do. Post a new question with before and after data;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with formatedtable as (
select 
left(a.ref1, LOCATE('_',a.ref1) - 1) as String, 
CAST(SUBSTR(a.ref1, LOCATE('_',a.ref1)+1) as DECIMAL) valdec
from yourtable a
)
select String, sum(valdec) total 
from formatedtable
group by String
```

If you are not sur always exist number into your string, try this:

```
with formatedtable as (
select 
left(a.ref1, LOCATE('_',a.ref1) - 1) as String, 
CAST(SUBSTR(a.ref1, LOCATE('_',a.ref1)+1) as DECIMAL) valdec
from yourtable a
where LOCATE('_',a.ref1)>0 and trim(SUBSTR(a.ref1, LOCATE('_',a.ref1)+1))<>'' 
and trim(translate(SUBSTR(a.ref1, LOCATE('_',a.ref1)+1), '          ', '0123456789'))='' 
)
select String, sum(valdec) total 
from formatedtable
group by String
```

Comment: CRRGW5628E An com.foundationdb.sql.parser.SQLParserException error occurred when validating the input SQL string, caused by Encountered " "with" "with "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting one of: "alter" ... "begin" ... "close" ... "commit" ... "create" ... "deallocate" ... "declare" ... "delete" ... "drop" ... "execute" ... "fetch" ... "insert" ... "prepare" ... "rollback" ... "select" ... "update" ... "values" ... "truncate" ... "call" ... "explain" ... "copy" ... "lock" ... "rename" ... "show" ... "{" ... "(" ... "?" ... ... .

Answer (score 0):

```
with formatedtable as (
select 
left(a.ref1, LOCATE('_',a.ref1) - 1) as String, 
CAST(SUBSTR(a.ref1, LOCATE('_',a.ref1)+1) as DECIMAL) valdec
from 
(SELECT DISTINCT T1.PROJECT_NAME,
       T1.REFERENCE_ID,
       T1.NAME AS URL1_title,
       T1.URL AS URL1,
       T1.REQUEST_TYPE,

        T2.VAL AS owner1,

     T2.VAL  ||'-'|| cast(T3.VAL AS CHAR(10)) AS ref1 ,
       T4.VAL AS owner2,
     T4.VAL  ||'-'||  cast(T5.VAL AS CHAR(10)) AS ref2 ,
       T6.VAL AS owner3,
     T6.VAL  ||'-'|| cast(T7.VAL AS CHAR(10)) AS ref3
FROM RIDW.VW_REQUEST T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T2
ON T2.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T2.NAME='owner_1'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_DECIMAL_EXT T3
  ON T3.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T3.NAME='resource1'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T4
    ON T4.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T4.NAME='owner_2'
      LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_DECIMAL_EXT T5
      ON T5.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T5.NAME='resource2'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T6
        ON T6.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T6.NAME='owner_3'
          LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_DECIMAL_EXT T7
          ON T7.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T7.NAME='resource'
WHERE T1.PROJECT_ID = 0  AND
(  T1.REQUEST_TYPE = 'Task' 
) AND
(T1.ISSOFTDELETED = 0) AND
(T1.REQUEST_ID <> -1 AND T1.REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY T2.VAL asc,
         T4.VAL asc,
         T6.VAL asc)a
)
SELECT valdec as ref
      FROM formatedtable
```

Comment: here is my query but how to edit it?please give me a any suggestion,it will be really helpfull for me

Comment: please give me a any idea

Comment: .... this would belong in the question, normally.  I think I'm a little more worried about what it implies of your db design, though.  Also, it implies that you're doing this to yourself, as you're concatenating `ref1`, when it would be far better to avoid doing that in the first place.